# Python map with list as input

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to construct permutations of a list with the i-th bit flipped every time.

For example:

With input:

```
[1,0,0,0]
```

To get:

```
[0,0,0,0]

[1,1,0,0]

[1,0,1,0]

[1,0,0,1]
```

I wrote a method which given a list returns the same list with the bit at position p changed:

```
def flipBit(l,p):
    l[p] = ~l[p]&1
    return l
```

And I'm trying to apply it using a `map()`, but I can't even get a basic example working:

```
p=list(map(flipBit, [[1,0,0]]*3,range(3))))
```

This is what it returns:

```
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

while expecting:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

What I'm I doing wrong? (if anyone can suggest an even shorter code for this maybe without using a flipbit method I'd appreciate it as I won't really use flipbit other than this purpose and I want to keep the code concise and clean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `[[1,0,0]]*3` creates a list containing three references *to the same sublist*. When you change one sublist, they all change.

Here is one way to fix this:

```
>>> list(map(flipBit, [[1,0,0] for _ in range(3)], range(3)))
                      ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

And here is a way to implement this functionality without using a helper function:

```
>>> l = [1, 0, 0]
>>> [l[:i] + [1-l[i]] + l[i+1:] for i in range(len(l))]
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted <s>is</s> was not valid at all, but I presume you need this:

```
>>> p=list(map(lambda x: flipBit([1, 0, 0], x), range(3)))
>>> p
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Basically, you map with a `lambda` function, that partially applies `[1, 0, 0]` as `l`, and then takes each element in `range(3)` and applies it to `p`.